# .dylib : How to get line number from address

Tags: c, debugging

I am trying to load a native shared library inside `java` on `Mac` but after loading, I get this error :

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x0000000127b325aa, pid=69795, tid=0x0000000000004903
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_202-b08) (build 1.8.0_202-b08)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.202-b08 mixed mode bsd-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [file.dylib+0x5f95aa]  _ZN2t513global_detail11wrap_globalINS_3jni11global_ref2IP8_jobjectEENS_15global_priority5otherEE12destroy_implEv+0x2a
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
```

I tried `atos -o file.dylib 0x0000000127b325aa 0x5f95aa`

It tells me the only the `function` where the error occurs but not the line number.

How to print complete stack trace and file and line number where the error occurs?

Comment: Recompile it in debug mode, attach a native debugger, and let it crash? Alternatively, feed the core dump to your debugger.

Comment: thanks. I compiled it with -g3 option and attached lldb debugger. its working now.